# Reading MiniTest failing messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have a failed test and I cannot seem to correctly read it.  How would you go about reading this:

```
FAIL["test_password_resets", PasswordResetsTest, 0.310017]
   test_password_resets#PasswordResetsTest (0.31s)
          expecting <"password_resets/new"> but rendering with <[]>
          test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'

    1/1: [===================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

  Finished in 0.31430s
  1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Where would I go to fix the error? it really doesn't give me more than the line number on the test sheet. But that doesn't really help me find the ultimate solution.

Here is the test:

```
    test "password resets" do
    get new_password_reset_path
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # invalid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/new'
    # valid email
    post password_resets_path, password_reset: { email: @user.email }
    assert_not_equal @user.reset_digest, @user.reload.reset_digest
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # password reset form
    user = assigns(:user)
    # wrong email
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: "")
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # inactive user
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    user.toggle!(:activated)
    # right email, wrong token
    get edit_password_reset_path('wrong token', email: user.email)
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # right email, right token
    get edit_password_reset_path(user.reset_token, email: user.email)
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    assert_select "input[name=email][type=hidden][value=?]", user.email
    # invalid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user: { password:              "foobaz",
                  password_confirmation: "barquux" }
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    # blank password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user: { password:              "  ",
                  password_confirmation: "  " }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_template 'password_resets/edit'
    # valid password & confirmation
    patch password_reset_path(user.reset_token),
          email: user.email,
          user: { password:              "foobaz",
                  password_confirmation: "foobaz" }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to user
  end
```

line 15 is "assert_template 'password_resets/new'" the first one, technically the 3rd line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) Make sure `new_password_reset_path` is a valid named route but running `rake routes` (2) Make sure your test recognize it by using `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

Comment: What is your controller test telling you for this route/request?  Is it rendering the template you expect with the response code you expect?

Comment: I'd add that this is an exceptionally complex set of interactions, even for an integration test.  10 controller requests is a lot, and my guess is that you could easily break this into 2 or 3 separate tests to make it more readable and manageable.

Comment: The problem was that new_password_reset_path was misspelled in my routes file. I did eventually break them up into 3 different tests to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of asserting that the template was rendered, try asserting that the response was what you expect, and *then* assert the template is correct.

```
assert_response :success
assert_template 'password_resets/new'
```

I suspect the request is getting redirected, which doesn't render a template.